# Coefficients in the asymptotic expansion for the product of modified Bessel functions $I_0(z) K_0(z)$

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

I am interested in the coefficients for the general term in the asymptotic expansion of $ I_0(z) K_0(z)$. Abramowitz and Stegun ([Equation 9.7.5](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_378.htm)) and all other available sources give the first two terms with the reference to [Equation 9.2.28](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_365.htm) for the development of the general term. Unfortunately also that formula is not quite clear: should the term with $ (2x)^8 $ in the denominator contain $ \frac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8} $ or $ \frac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 24} $ ? Where can one find the explicit form for the general term?

Comment: The general form of the expansion for $M_\nu^2$ is given in Olver, *Asymptotics and Special Functions* (with the final derivation left as an exercise). The fraction is just $1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2 k - 1)/(2 \cdot 4 \cdots 2 k)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maxim, I did not know that source.